# PHP mail Cc is not working

Tags: php, email

My code is working fine, and I am receiving mail, but the Cc mail is not receiving, and there is no error showing up:

This is my code:

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$cat=$_POST['cat'];
$date=date("y-m-d");

$emailList="abc@yahoo.com,abc123@gmail.com";

$to = "to@gmail.com";
$subject .= "Query";
$headers .= "cc: ".$emailList."\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$email."\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: php";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = "Name: ".$name."\r\n";
$message .= "Mobile: ".$mobile."\r\n";
$message .= "Email ID: ".$email."\r\n";
$message .= "Query For: ".$cat."\r\n";
$retval = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

Comment: `$headers` not `$header`.

Comment: You should also assign $headers an initial value before attempting to concatenate onto it.

Comment: @JonStirling updated the code but not receiving the cc

Comment: @Rids Try `CC` instead of `cc`

Answer (score 0):

Typo error.
Change to:

```
$retval = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: it is a typo. also you didn't have to copy all of the code. You could've just added the line you changed.

Comment: ok sorry, I'm new in stack ... and trying to help (edited post)

Answer (score -2):

I have tested the code in my localhost server and It is working fine.

```
$emailList="cc1p@gmail.com, cc2@gmail.com";

$to = "to@gmail.com";
$subject = "Query";
$headers = "cc: ".$emailList."\r\n";
$headers .= "From: "."my mail"."\r\n" ."X-Mailer: php";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = "message";
$retval = mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
```

Comment: updated but not recieving the mail

Comment: $subject .= "Query";
$headers .= "cc: ".$emailList."\r\n";
Remove dot(.) from both line like:
$subject = "Query";
$headers = "cc: ".$emailList."\r\n";

Comment: Please see my updated answer and it will work fine. It is tested.